# Same exact package.json file works in empty brand new project but doesn't in old project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I get this error when I try to upgrade to Angular 8.

> npm WARN old lockfile
>
> npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an
> old version of npm,
>
> npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from
> the registry.
>
> npm WARN old lockfile
>
> npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
>
> npm WARN old lockfile
>
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
>
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! While resolving: comprehensivedashboard@0.0.0
>
> npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@7.2.6
>
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
>
> npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"~8.2.14" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@">=7.0.0" from
> @angular/material@7.3.3
>
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
>
> npm ERR!     @angular/material@"~8.2.3" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>
> npm ERR! @angular/animations@"~8.2.14" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@8.2.14
>
> npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
>
> npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"8.2.14" from @angular/animations@8.2.14
>
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
>
> npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~8.2.14" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
>
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
>
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
> resolution.
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\vakkinen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a
> full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> C:\Users\vakkinen\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-05T12_19_50_257Z-debug.log

So decided to create a brand new Angular8 app and see what the package.json file looks like. That file is attached below. Then I added all the packages I need to this brand new empty project one at a time. The application build succeeded and I was able to run the application. So I copied and pasted all the dependencies and devDependencies to the old project package.json. That project still fails `npm i` because of the same error above. So I tried to clone the repo into a new directory and replaced the contents of the package.json with the contents of the package.json from the brand new empty project, still the same error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^11.0.0",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.15.0-sr.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-csv": "^0.3.1",
    "ngx-export-as": "1.4.2",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",    
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting package-lock.json and re running the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a file called package-lock in the same folder as the package file. Delete it and the error should go away. The package-lock file contains all dependencies of your dependencies and their versions. Deleting it doesn’t affect your project since it’s regenerated on npm install.

Answer (score 2):

The error message warns you that the **package-lock.json** file is the issue. Just delete it and a new one will be generated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue stems from having incorrect files in the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json`.

Most probably the easiest solution is to delete both the `node_modules` directory and the package-lock.json and then running a `npm install` to get a clean `node_modules` directory and a new `package-lock.json` according to your `package.json`

I recommend reading more about what the package-lock.json file is for here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8

Answer (score 1):

Steps to fix this issue:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder.
2. Delete `package-lock.json`.
3. Run `npm i --force`.